# How to add formatting to, and batch rename filenames?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, file-rename, batch-rename

I have around 7,000 .txt files that have been spat out by a program where the naming convention clearly broke. The only saving grace is that they follow the following structure: id, date, time.

`m031060209104704.txt` --> id:`m031` date:`060209` time:`104704`.txt

Sample of other filenames (again same thing):

`115-060202105710.txt` --> id:`115-` date:`060202` time: `105710`.txt

`x138051203125338.txt` etc...

`9756060201194530.txt` etc..

**I want to rename all 7,000 files in this directory to look like the following:**

`m031060209104704.txt` --> **`090206_104704_m031`.txt**

i.e date_time_id (each separated by underscores or hyphens, I don't mind). **I need the date format to be switched from yymmdd to ddmmyy as shown directly above though!**

I'm not clear on whats overkill here, full program script or bash command (MAC OS). Again, I don't mind, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: What have you attempted? There are plenty of examples of similar file renaming right here on Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Ive tried using `grep` and `rename` so far but no luck, especially with the date format switch around

Comment: if you have the `rename` tool (perl version), you can rename filenames with a similar syntax to `sed` substitute.

Comment: you'd really do better to reconsider `ddmmyy` as your format. using `yyyymmdd` naturally date sorts all of your files and removes the ambiguity of is that a year day or month value at the front of the string. There are a lot of ways of solving this problem, with `awk` you can do things like `awk '{mon=substr($0,7,2);print "mon="mon}' file` (you'll have to get the exact position instead of `7` for the start of mon, then do the same for other parts of your file to rename. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory to store renamed files
newdir="./renamed"
mkdir -p $newdir

for file in *.txt; do
    if [[ $file =~ ^(....)([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{6})\.txt$ ]]; then
        # extract parameters
        id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        yy=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        mm=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        dd=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        time=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}

        # then rearrange them to new name
        newname=${dd}${mm}${yy}_${time}_${id}.txt

        # move to new directory
        mv "$file" "$newdir/$newname"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for what I needed, also much easier to understand than the `sed` and regex's I was trying a few hours ago! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Bash string indexes makes it very easy and efficient to rework the filenames as you intend. You should also validate you are only operating on input filenames of 20 characters. That can be accomplished as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.txt; do
    ## validate a 20 character filename
    (( ${#i} == 20 )) || { printf "invalid length '%s'\n" "$i"; continue; }
    echo "mv $i ${i:8:2}${i:6:2}${i:4:2}_${i:10:6}_${i:0:4}.txt" ## output rename
    mv "$i" "${i:8:2}${i:6:2}${i:4:2}_${i:10:6}_${i:0:4}.txt"    ## actual rename
done
```

**Example Directory**

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    0 Dec 21 19:16 115-060202105710.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    0 Dec 21 19:16 9756060201194530.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    0 Dec 21 19:15 m031060209104704.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    0 Dec 21 19:16 x138051203125338.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ cd thedir
$ bash ../script.sh
mv 115-060202105710.txt 020206_105710_115-.txt
mv 9756060201194530.txt 010206_194530_9756.txt
mv m031060209104704.txt 090206_104704_m031.txt
mv x138051203125338.txt 031205_125338_x138.txt

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Dec 21 19:42 010206_194530_9756.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Dec 21 19:42 020206_105710_115-.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Dec 21 19:42 031205_125338_x138.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Dec 21 19:42 090206_104704_m031.txt
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Ahh... Gotcha, hold on `:)`